# Procedure call inside transaction

Tags: transactions, procedure, postgresql-11

I have stored procedure which consinsts of several update queries on table.  It uses data from several other tables. So each query is commited inside procedure, to release locks on tables used in query.
At some point i need to create temp tables with some test data. Temp table names are same as of persistent tables to shadow persistent tables. And I want to use "on commit drop" but, if I begin transaction temp table creation goes smoothly, but on call my_very_big_procedure() I'm getting an error "wrong end of transaction" and points to first commit inside procedure.

To keep code short i'l use some dummy example:

```
create or replace procedure my_very_big_procedure() as 
$$ 
begin
   insert into maintable select from table1, some_table, some_other_table;
   commit;

   update maintable using table1;
   commit;

   update maintable using table2;
   commit;
end;
$$ language pgplsql

begin
    create temp table maintable (like public.maintable) on commit drop;
    create temp table table1 (like public.table1) on commit drop -- works fine
    insert into table1 values %s  -- also works fine
    create temp table table2 (like public.table2) on commit drop -- again it's OK
    insert into table2 values %s -- and data's got inserted
    call my_very_big_procedure() -- and here comes an ERROR :(
    commit
end
```

So how can I use procedure call inside a transaction block?

UPD:
Well, seems I have to create temp tables in session and drop them manually.  Have to use table oid's to ensure that temp table exists then.
Like this I think:

```
select case when 'public.teblename'::regclass::oid = 'tablename'::regclass::oid then 'temp table exitsts' else 'no temp table - no drop' end.
```

Answer (score 1):

> *So how can I use procedure call inside a transaction block?*

You can't, as mentioned in the [doc page for CALL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-call.html):

> **If CALL is executed in a transaction block, then the called procedure
>   cannot execute transaction control statements.**

The sequence of statements shown in the question wouldn't work anyway, because the procedure wants to update a temporary table that would have been dropped by the commit just above that update.

Comment: Daaamn, that sad :(